# Escaping converting Danish characters by JTidy

Tags: jtidy

I'm using JTidy to parse an HTML page to a XHTML. The HTML contains danish characters then the JTidy converts them in to some specific characters.

eg : 
Word "Observér" is converted to  "ObservÃ©r".

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: The issue is solved with HtmlCleaner lib.